# Odoo Boolean Graph?

Tags: python, xml, nvd3.js, odoo

I'd like to display a graph in odoo. in which i have two fields:

Date in the x-axis.

Boolean in the y-axis.

odoo use the nvd3.js to display this charts,

this is the view.xml:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="id_view">
            <field name="name">test.base.graph.view16</field>
            <field name="model">module.base</field>
            <field name="type">graph</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <graph string="test" type="bar" >
                     <field name="date" interval="day" type="row"/>
                     <field name="boolean" type="measure"/>                  
                </graph>
            </field>
</record>
```

this code doesn't work for me, it return an empty graph. any one have idea about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Simulate both fields as integers, one by one.

*Clearer:*
Add two additional fields:

`'date_sim': fields.integer("Date simulation"),
 'bool_sim': fields.integer("Bool simulation")`

And for the first two fields, just add two methods decorated by *@api.onchange*
And in their bodies just update the *_sim* fields with corresponding values.

And at last you should use the new fields in your view.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to change the Type of the fields (from boolean to integer).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="id_view">
    <field name="name">test.base.graph.view16</field>
    <field name="model">module.base</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <graph string="test" type="bar" stacked="True" interval="day">
            <field name="date" type="row" interval="day"/>
            <field name="boolean" type="measure"/>
        </graph>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I try your solution but it doesn't work for me.